# Create c# object array of undefined length?

Tags: c#, arrays

I would like to create an object array in C# of undefined length and then populate the array in a loop like so...

```
    string[] splitWords = message.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });

    Word[] words = new Word[];
    int wordcount = 0;
    foreach (string word in splitWords)
    {
        if (word == "") continue;
        words[wordcount] = new Word(word);
        wordcount++;
    }
```

However, I get the error... 
"Array creation must have array size or array initializer"

I'm doing a lot more logic in the foreach loop that I've left out for brevity.

Comment: Need you use an array? Doing this sort of thing with a List is often a lot easier - and can be more performant (in my experience anyway).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

What you want to do is create:

```
List<Word> words = new List<Word>();
```

and then:

```
words.Add(new Word(word));
```

And finally when the loop is done if you need an array:

```
words.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're using C# 3.5, you can just do the following.

```
var words = message
  .Split(new char[]{' '}) 
  .Where(x => x != "")
  .Select(x => new Word(x))
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: If there's not a LINQ solution to your problem, you're not trying hard enough :)  Nice one.

Comment: Good stuff. A note, using StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries as your second Split() parameter would eliminate the Where() call. Although it's longer, it saves another loop through the string array.

Answer (score 7):

You can't create an array of undefined length. This is where you'd use a generic List.

```
List<Word> words = new List<Word>();
```

Answer (score 1):

A friendly note, you can pass option to split to ignore empty entries.  Assuming no other logic to prune out entries you can preinitialize your array like so:

```
string[] splitWords = message.Split(new Char[] {' '},
  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Word[] words = new Word[splitWords.Length];
```

Comment: Thanks, I did this based on another comment to an answer.  Thanks, I had not yet discovered this option.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new list and convert to array...

```
var words = new List<Word>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you may use list to populate your words first and then convert it easily to array like this:

```
string[] splitWords = message.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });

List<Word> words = new List<Word>();
int wordcount = 0;
foreach (string word in splitWords)
{
    if (word == "") continue;
    words.add(new Word(word));
    //wordcount++;
}

wordcount = words.count;
return words.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why can't we just use a string variable (say `x`), initialize it and retrieve comma separated data in it and later use `string[]` variable (say `y[]`) and initialize it equal to `x.Split(',')` without having to initialize a blank array like follows:

```
string x = string.Empty;
string msg = "hi,how,r,u,xyz";

void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     x = msg;
     string[] y = msg.Split(',');
```

I think this should work as needed but I didn't try running this so I am not sure. If someone thinks that my solution is wrong, please correct me.

Answer (score -2):

I solved it by using an ArrayList and then casting it to the object array after iterating...

```
    string[] splitWords = message.Split(new Char[] {' '});
    ArrayList wordList = new ArrayList();
    int wordcount = 0;
    foreach (string word in splitWords)
{
        if (word == "") continue;
        Word newWord = new Word(word);
        wordList.Add(newWord);
        wordcount++;
}
    Word[] words = (Word[])wordList.ToArray(typeof(Word));
```

I've heard the whole "create question/answer just to document it for others" is acceptable.  Plus I'd like to hear if there are better suggestions.  Thanks.

Comment: The other answers (ie. List<Word>) is generlaly considered better, as the ToArray() is less code, and it's type-safe (you can't accidentally put non-Words in it.

Comment: Great answer of using a generic List... not sure why I didn't think of that first.  Thanks!  Also, I guess putting my first guess as an "answer" was not such a good idea considering the down votes and ding to my rep!  ha